# To get list of security groups

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have used below code to get list of security groups for a user from Active directory, But i am getting all the groups for the user from Active directory,can you help me in getting only the list of SECURITY GROUPS for a user from Active Directory?

```
public List<string> getSecurityGroup(string userName,SearchInfo searchInfo, Error errorInfo)
        {
            List<string> groups =new List<string>() ;
            try
            {
                string ldapPath = @"LDAP://" + searchInfo.HostName + @"/" + searchInfo.SearchDN;
                DirectoryEntry obEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);

                DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(obEntry,
                    "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")");
                SearchResult res = srch.FindOne();
                if (null != res)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry obUser = new DirectoryEntry(res.Path);
                    // Invoke Groups method.
                    object obGroups = obUser.Invoke("Groups");
                    foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
                    {
                        // Create object for each group.
                        DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
                        groups.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
                    }
                 }
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException comException)
            {
                errorInfo.ErrorCode = comException.ErrorCode;
                errorInfo.ErrorMessage = comException.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                errorInfo.ErrorCode = -1;
                errorInfo.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
            }
            return groups;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look at the groupType attribute, e.g. you can search for security groups using:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))
```

BTW another way to get all groups of which a given user is a member (directly or indirectly) is to use the search filter:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<user-distinguished-name>)
```

You can combine this with the groupType filter.  For more info see [this MSDN article on Search Filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx).

**UPDATE**

> Can you tell me in which part of the code i have to modify?

The above is a filter, to pass as a parameter to the `DirectorySearcher` method.  E.g. the following should create a list of the `sAMAccountName` of each security group of which `userrName` is a member, directly or indirectly:

```
List<string> groups = new List<string>();
using (var root = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
{
    using(var srch = new DirectorySearcher(root, 
                   "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")"))
    {
        SearchResult res = srch.FindOne();
        if (res != null)
        {
            string dn = (string) res.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
            string filter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))",
                dn);
            using (var groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher(root, filter, new[] { "sAMAccountName" }))
            {
                groupSearch.PageSize = 1000;
                using (var resultCollection = groupSearch.FindAll())
                {
                    foreach (SearchResult result in resultCollection)
                    {
                        groups.Add((string) result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply... I have tried the above code but i could not achieve the result. Can you tell me in which part of the code i have to modify? either in the Invoke methoed? of in the Directory seacher parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: that looks a lot like C#, not java. Why are you posting with tag Java?

Secondly: In AD, security groups should belong to the OU "Security Groups". So examine the distinguished name of each group. If it contains "`OU=Security Groups`" it should be a security group.

Alternatively, you can fetch the groups record and examine the `sAMAccountType` attribute. Security groups should have the value 0x10000000 (268435456 decimal).

EDIT:
Not being fully fluent in C# I can't vouch for exact correctness, but maybe try something like this:

```
foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
{
    // Create object for each group.
    DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
    if (obGpEntry.Path.ToLower().contains("ou=security groups")) {
        groups.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response,I cannot understand your reply, can you tell me in the code, in which line modification is required and what modification is required?Is it the line object obGroups = obUser.Invoke("Groups"); ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, i could not achieve the result of what i need. May be i need to try some alternative method

Comment: @pap : The code worked for me..
Is there some other way to get the group names without creating the `DirectoryEntry` in every `foreach` loop....??

Comment: @sandy No idea, don't know C# that well.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. There is no guarntee that OU=Security group for all the security grops. For example in our organization, OU section is marked as Security .